# About mutual_info_classif in sklearn, so confused about usage of random_state in terms of feature selection

Tags: random, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I used mutual_info_classif and selectPercentile from sklearn to do the feature selection in a dataset. I found that I can set the random_state to be 0 to make sure selected features can be same every time such like below the code:

```
mi = mutual_info_classif(X_train, y_train, random_state=0)
print(mi)
sel_mi = SelectPercentile(mutual_info_classif, percentile=10).fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Another one, I do not need to set random_state and make it be default one. But this will make every selection will be different.

```
mi = mutual_info_classif(X_train, y_train)
```

I want to know that if the feature selection every time will be same, how can I judge if it is the best feature choices?

If the selection is different every time, whether does it mean that this kind of feature selection is meaningless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ML is more of an art than of a science. Some algos will return always the same, regardless of seed, e.g. linear regression, others, e.g. decision trees, will return different results depending on subsample, and some, e.g. random forest, may return different results even on the same subsample depending on seed.

An algo, returning different results depending on subsample, means your algo depends on the data distribution, and that may change depending on seed your're providing. It doesn't mean your algo is useless. You may pay more attention to features that consistently appear most important regradless of data subsample you're providing.

You may get a more consistent results by providing more data, thus, getting more consistent results from sampling in terms of data distribution.

Final remark. Feature importance might seem an important exercise in terms of exploring your data, what you have to pay more attention to while collecting or cleaning your data. But it's not so important in terms of model building, as most algos have built in mechanisms of feature selection.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. According to my understanding, I think you means it is important to pay attention to features that appear consistently. It means we must do several experiments to confirm which feature is important to model. But how can I judge how many experiments I need to do until I found the best feature combination? Is more and more tests more beneficial to find best result?

Comment: As I said, it's more of an art than of a science. How many tests, or CV splits, it's your decision. BTW, if you look even at simplest linear regression on small data, if you run it on different samples you may have gotten different results. And then you have to make conclusions about what model is best (what is most important in your parlor).

Comment: Finding the same important feature set is not your task here. In real life you're always dealing with samples, you never see the *full* dataset (until you lived forever and life stops tomorrow). Your real task is to find on those subsamples features that consistently perform best, regardless of how wierd the subsample is. Of course, you don't have to go to extremes, and you have to make it sure your subsamples are more or less similar to your understanding of what *real* data is. In such a way, your model might miss a target once in while, but it will of higher performance in the long run.

Comment: Target for more data, and fair subsampling, not for the same feature importances.